# input=file change doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html

I have this, and I don't understand why doesn't work . In the demo it works normal.
The debugger doesn't enter in the function readImage(file) and in console this.files is undefined.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ImagesAnatation.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> // var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL; // alternate use

            function readImage(file) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                var image = new Image();

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function (_file) {
                    image.src = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
                    image.onload = function () {
                        var w = this.width,
                            h = this.height,
                            t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                            n = file.name,
                            s = ~~(file.size / 102) + 'KB';
                        $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
                    };
                    image.onerror = function () {
                        alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
                    };
                };

            }
            $("#choose").change(function (e) {
                if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
                var F = this.files;
                if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
            });

        </script>
    <style>#uploadPreview img{
  height:400px;
}</style>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Multiple image upload with preview by Roko C.B.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe the input needs an onchange attribute?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6xL4J/ It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your jquery code in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler, otherwise the script won't find the targeted elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function readImage(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image = new Image();

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function (_file) {
            image.src = _file.target.result; // url.createObjectURL(file);
            image.onload = function () {
                var w = this.width,
                    h = this.height,
                    t = file.type, // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                    n = file.name,
                    s = ~~ (file.size / 102) + 'KB';
                $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
            };
            image.onerror = function () {
                alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
            };
        };

    }
    $("#choose").change(function (e) {
        if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
        var F = this.files;
        if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
    });
});
```